# CLI view of Software changes

Tags: command-line, software-center, log

I often install software, remove software, upgrade it etc, and sometimes I need to check on recent changes such as these that I have made. But to do this currently I am having to open the Ubuntu Software Center, which is something I hate doing because I am a more of a CLI than a GUI person, plus it's hugely bulky and takes ages to load, and takes up lots of RAM. So I was wondering how I can view recent software changes in Terminal which would basically show more or less the same thing as the Ubuntu Software Center in the History section, but in Terminal?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All dpkg history is stored in

```
 /var/log/dpkg.log
```

If you specifically want apt-get history, you'll find it in .

```
  /var/log/apt/history.log
```